# Can't access one website by Requests (Python Library) but working under PostMan(Chrome App)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I tried to access one website hosted with IIS by Python Requests, and the website is enabled basic auth and disable other auth methods.

**Below is my codes:**

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

xxx_headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36',
               'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
               'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
               'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
               'Connection':'keep-alive',
               'Cache-Control':'no-cache'}
response = requests.get('http://test:180/test.ashx', headers=xxx_headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('wsguest', 'xxxx'))

print ('------------finished---------------')
if(response.ok):
    print('success')
else:
    response.raise_for_status()
```

**Below is the output:**

```
------------finished---------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jianc\Desktop\test\test_print.py", line 25, in <module>
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\jianc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://test:180/test.aspx

#Partial Response Text:
<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href="http://test:180/test.aspx">http://test:180/test.aspx</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Access Denied.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p>Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo>webmaster</a>.</p>
<br>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="footer">
<p>Generated Mon, 05 Feb 2018 23:14:44 GMT by proxy.test.com (squid/3.5.12)</p>
<!-- ERR_ACCESS_DENIED -->
</div>
</body></html>
```

If I changed the URL to 'https://www.google.com', 'http://www.baidu.com' or others, it works (returned http status code=200).

[image: Simulated in PostMan]

Also I simulated one Post/Get to same URL with same auth in PostMan(Chrome App), it still works.

But if ran the codes generated by the PostMan, it failed with same error.

***I suspected the error was caused by the script is run under CUI instead of GUI, GUI will run under the proxy environment of OS, and CUI may not. But why still succeeded to access google.com? If auth failed at proxy server, it should reject all requests including to 'google and other website'.***

Already tried many solutions (like adding proxy with/without basic auth), but no luck.

Many thanks if anyone can provide any hint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I caught the root cause.

Httplib2 doesn't catch&apply OS proxy setting.

Requests does automatically catch&apply OS proxy setting.

That is why the HTTP request was rejected (**NTLM** Auth Failed in Proxy) when using Python Requests.

So the solution is simple, ignore the OS proxy in the codes (For Python Requests lib).

Another way is implement Proxy NTLM Auth, but it will be complicated, at least I didn't find out any related codes in the internet.

Below codes works:

```
import httplib2

h = httplib2.Http(".cache")

h.add_credentials('xxx', 'xxxx') # Basic authentication

resp, content = h.request("http://test:180/test.aspx", "GET", body="")
print (content)
```

Below codes are generated by PostMan, then it will work if ignore default OS proxy (two solutoins: disables gobal proxy setting or uses empty proxy instead).

```
import requests
url = "http://test:180/test.aspx"
session = requests.Session()
session.trust_env = False #disable OS proxy
headers = {
    'authorization': "Basic d3NndWVzdDpzbWMxxjMhQA==",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "157e52fa-95f5-5287-9ee0-xxxxxxxx"
}

response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)

#use empty proxy instead
proxies = {
  "http": None,
  "https": None,
}
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('test', 'test'), proxies=proxies)
print (response)
```

Comment: use wireshark to check what difference both frames have.

Comment: It's pretty clear that the authorization header is different between Postman/httplib2 and what requests is generating using the auth=HTTPBasicAuth('wsguest', 'xxxx') param.  Try adding the authorization header to the requests headers param and remove the auth.  If that works, I'd compare the authorization header created by the auth param vs the ones you are hard coding.

Comment: @William I did try this way, but no luck. It looks something special in the header caused the request was blocked by the Squid proxy. I will dig it out (have to use wireshark or fiddler to compare the http packets) after finish urgent projects onhand.

Comment: @eyllanesc, Updated the answers. I find out the differences by using wireshark. The HTTP requests generated by Python Requests were re-directed to ip.dst=[proxy server], but Httplib2 not. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: because my IIS website is in internal network. so the request should not been redirected by the proxy.